# How to specify Django UniqueConstraint for GeoDjango PointField to prevent duplicate points within some tolerance

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I'd like to ensure that users cannot enter duplicate coordinates in my database (stored as a geodjango `PointField`).

Django's `UniqueConstraint` feature permits this, but to my knowledge only excludes *exact* matches. It would be more useful to prevent coordinates being within some tolerance (e.g. 1m) of one another.

Is there an easy way of achieving this with `UniqueConstraint`? Or if not, what is the best approach? E.g. perhaps writing some custom SQL for `BaseConstraint`?